# getting custom made LWUIT UIID from theme to set style in netbeans

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I've created a `Button` with another UIID (Buttonx) instead of the default `Button` because there are other buttons that will inherit the default `Button` UIID. the problem is accessing the UIID style(Buttonx) from the theme to style the newly created `Button` that I want to have the characteristics of Buttonx.
I could set the styles in netbeans for the new button but it is not overriding the default `Button` properties set in the theme. please help

Answer (score 1):

So, you can set the UIID propierties to a `Button`by code but you can't modify this style from code. What you need to do is, create the style in the Resource editor and set the name Buttonx. Now in the code, set the UIID Buttonx to the `Components`what you want with `button.setUIID("Buttonx");`. This `Components`will have the Buttonx style propierties.